# How do I specify "code" property when my code is actually taken from AWS codecommit repo?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

This question is in relation to a cloudformation template which tries to create lambda functions. The template is in codecommit and uses codepipeline to create tha lambda. But I am struggling to specify the "code" property. The actual code for the lambda function is in my codecommit repo. Below is the example on AWS documentation. But below code appears to take the code from a S3 bucket. Do I specify the file name? if so in what format, thank you.

```
AMIIDLookup: 
  Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
  Properties: 
    Handler: "index.handler"
    Role: 
      Fn::GetAtt: 
        - "LambdaExecutionRole"
        - "Arn"
    Code: 
      S3Bucket: "lambda-functions"
      S3Key: "amilookup.zip"
    Runtime: "nodejs8.10"
    Timeout: 25
    TracingConfig:
      Mode: "Active"
```

Further info - Here is my cloudformation template- which is pushed to the codecommit repo. Templete and the pipeline work perfectly with inline code. But I do not know how to specify the code to be taken from the file in the code commit repo. E.g. if the code is in a file - ./abc/index.js

```
Resources: 
  LFVQS1: 
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function' 
    Properties: 
      Handler: 'index.function_name**' 
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::561731601292:role/service-role/mailfwd-role-m5rl5tu3' 
      Runtime: "nodejs8.10" 
      Code: { 
        ZipFile: "exports.wrtiteToConsole = function (event, context, callback){ console.log('Hello'); callback(null); }" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking in the context of CodePipeline (based on the tags), you can either use the ParameterOverrides configuration property of the CloudFormation action to reference the CodePipeline artifact (stored in S3) or use the S3 publish action and reference the location in your CloudFormation template.

CloudFormation action reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html

Comment: Thank you. I added bit more info, please see if that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: You need to change `index.handler` to `abc/index.handler` (basically the path to the JS file in the ZIP and handler is the name of the function that Lambda should invoke).

Comment: But ehn what do I our in "code" parameter. If I do not put it, it says "Property Code cannot be empty."

Comment: Code should be a tuple (S3 bucket and object) - use ParameterOverrides to dynamically specify these as template parameters.